# Estimating unobserved variance

Tags: variance, markov-chain-montecarlo

I'm analyzing codon usage using the model described in the following paper

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4494061/

In brief, this model uses a MCMC to estimate the pausing time for the codons $\Delta\eta$, among other parameters which do not concern me at the moment. Estimates are obtained within synonymous codon families, eg. the estimates for the codons of one amino acid are independent of the estimates from the other amino acids. All $\Delta\eta$ estimates within a codon family are made relative to a reference codon, which has a fixed $\Delta\eta$ = 0. In other words, if a codon family has N codons, the model will estimate $\Delta\eta$ values for N-1 codons, and the reference will have a $\Delta\eta$ value of 0.

We wish to compare the $\Delta\eta$ values estimated from two different regions of a protein, which we were doing using a Model-II regression approach and seeing if the estimated line is significantly different from the $y = x$ line. If selection on codon usage differs in these regions, this will result in differences in the $\Delta\eta$ estimates. We found our conclusions were variant to the choice of reference codon, which we resolved by rescaling all of the $\Delta\eta$ values within a codon family, including the reference codon, to have a mean of 0. For making our comparisons, we would like to know the variance of the different $\Delta\eta$ estimates. As these parameters are estimated with a MCMC, we obtain estimates of the $\Delta\eta$ variance from the MCMC samples. However, in the model, all of these parameters are based on codon counts in the regions of interest, which are subject to natural variation. This means even though the reference codon is fixed at 0, this value is also subject to variation centered around 0. If this is the case, then this variation in the reference codon gets propagated to the estimates of the other $\Delta\eta$ values during the MCMC...or at least this is how we are thinking about it at the moment.

My question:
In this case, is there a good way to estimate or handle the unobserved variance for the reference codons? My solution to the problem thus far has been to redistribute the total variance for a codon family (the sum of the $\Delta\eta$ variance estimates) evenly across the codons within that codon family. Generally, I see little variation in the $\Delta\eta$ variance estimates within each codon family, so it does not seem completely unreasonable to assume equal variance within a codon family. Does my solution sound reasonable? If not, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "MCMC" as such cannot be used to estimate anything without having a model.  It is difficult to understand what is going on here - could you explain what data you have, what your model looks like and what is the purpose of "comparing these estimates for two different points"

Comment: My apologies. I hope my edits clarify my problem.